Polygons with holes in SVG
i am having a hard time to understand how i would generate holes in polygons of an svg file.
this would be an example:


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="100%" height="100%"
  viewBox="2.529975092957109 41.346880553423844 23.168975806780242 22.134355770447257"
  stroke-width="0.00250">
  <defs>

  </defs>
  <polygon fill="black" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    points="12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749" />
  <polygon fill="black" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    points="14.179,52.626 14.179,52.336 13.515,52.336 13.515,52.626 14.179,52.626" />
  <polygon fill="red" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    points="14.492,52.433 14.492,52.261 14.906,52.261 14.906,52.433 14.492,52.433" />

</svg>



what would i need to change here in order to make the polygons intersect each other?
Thanks a lot!

I'm not very sure what you are asking. Do you want the second polygon to be a hole in the first one?

yes. there are two rectangles within each other. one should cut a hole in the other one

1. I'm transforming the polygons to paths. For this I've changed the points attribute to a d attribute. Also I'm adding the M command at the begining of the string of values.
From:
points="12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749"

to:
d="M12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749"

This is enough, although I would add add the L command for the lines.
d="M12.669,52.749 L12.669,52.075 L14.391,52.075 L14.391,52.749 L12.669,52.749"

2. I concatenate the d attribute of the two paths.
d="M12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749
   M14.179,52.626 14.179,52.336 13.515,52.336 13.515,52.626 14.179,52.626"

In this case it will create a hole since the second part of the path (after the second M command) is drawn in the opposite direction (one rectangle drawn clockwise and the other anti-clockwise).
In other cases you may need to add fill-rule="evenodd" to the path.
Please read about the fill-rule attribute


<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="100%" height="100%"
  viewBox="12 52 3 3"
  stroke-width="0.00250">
  <path fill="black" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    d="M12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749
    M14.179,52.626 14.179,52.336 13.515,52.336 13.515,52.626 14.179,52.626"/>   

</svg>




You could use a mask to cut a hole. Here, the smaller square is used both in a mask and for creating the stroke around the hole. The mask is applied to the bigger square.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="12 52 3 3" stroke-width="0.00250">
  <defs>
    <polygon id="hole" 
      stroke-linecap="square"
      stroke-linejoin="miter"
      points="14.179,52.626 14.179,52.336 13.515,52.336 13.515,52.626 14.179,52.626" />
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect x="12" y="52" width="3" height="3" fill="white" />
      <use href="#hole" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <polygon fill="black" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    mask="url(#m1)"
    points="12.669,52.749 12.669,52.075 14.391,52.075 14.391,52.749 12.669,52.749" />
  <use href="#hole" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002" />
  <polygon fill="red" fill-opacity=".1" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.002"
    stroke-linecap="square"
    stroke-linejoin="miter"
    points="14.492,52.433 14.492,52.261 14.906,52.261 14.906,52.433 14.492,52.433" />
</svg>



